# What are the costs of many trainable parameters and layers in Machine Learning?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I'm curious as to what effect many trainable parameters have on a machine learning algorithm.

For instance, a CNN with many layers can extract more abstract data from images. But more layers means more trainable parameters. What downsides exist for making really deep models?

Do more params mean more RAM is required to load the model?

Do more params mean the model is computationally expensive i.e. requires better hardware to train?

Do more params mean the model takes longer to train and classify or is the change negligible in most cases?

I noticed that deeper models with more params have a larger file size when the models are saved are there any other costs?.

Most sources I can find on this topic just mention keeping the params low but never elaborate and why exactly we do this.

Comment: also, consider the optimization part... increasing the number of variables would definitely make it harder to find the global minimum and not the local ones.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming as defined in the [help] but about ML theory and/or methodology - please see the intro and NOTE in the `machine-learning` [tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/machine-learning/info).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do more params mean more RAM is required to load the model?

Yes, it requires more RAM/VRAM depending on your training mode.

> Do more params mean the model is computationally expensive i.e.
> requires better hardware to train?

Yes.

> Do more params mean the model takes longer to train and classify or is
> the change negligible in most cases?

Yes it takes longer as the number of calculations increases.

> I noticed that deeper models with more params have a larger file size
> when the models are saved are there any other costs?.

Aside from what you have already pointed out? Yes, The optimization can be affected, the training regime is affected.

> Most sources I can find on this topic just mention keeping the params
> low but never elaborate and why exactly we do this.

When the number of trainable parameters increases, the number of calculations also increases, this denotes an increase in the hardware requirements, both in form of RAM and processing power.
It also introduces difficulties in terms of optimization such as overfitting or even altogether, the choice of the optimization algorithm used.

The transfer of the model can become an issue depending on your use case, for example, consider, IoT devices, drones, autonomous vehicles/robots that require updates, etc, bad/poor connection speed, etc and stuff like this. (There are ways to reduce the model size and increase its performance, but in general, the more parameters means more space/time)